# Как с помощью d3.js сделать стрелочки вместо линий?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, d3.js

Рисую граф, переделав force.js примера связи d3 и networkx. Код зарисовки графа:

```
var margin = 30;
var w = 700 - 2 * margin, h = 500 - 2 * margin;
var svg = d3.select("#plot").append("svg")
                .attr("width", w + 2 * margin)
                .attr("height", h + 2 * margin)
            .append("svg:g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + ", " + margin + ")");


// Axes scaling functions.
var xscale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]);
var yscale = d3.scale.linear().range([h, 0]);

// The axes objects themselves.
var xaxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xscale).ticks(8);
var yaxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yscale).ticks(8).orient("left");

svg.append("svg:g").attr("class", "x axis")
                   .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + h + ")");
svg.append("svg:g").attr("class", "y axis");

// Load the data.
var callback = function (data) {


    // Insert the data points.
    fill = d3.scale.category20();


  var force = d3.layout.force()
              .charge(-120)
              .linkDistance(30)
              .nodes(data.nodes)
              .links(data.links)
              .size([w, h])
              .start();


  var link = svg.selectAll("line.link")
      .data(data.links)
    .enter().append("svg:line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value);       })
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  var node = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
      .data(data.nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("svg:title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });



    svg.style("opacity", 1e-6)
        .transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .style("opacity", 1);

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });

};

d3.json("/data", callback);
```

Что и как мне нужно поменять, чтобы вместо линий получить направленные стрелки, соединяющие вершины графа? Знаю, что требуется использовать пути и рисовать стрелочку отдельно, но как это сделать - не в курсе.

Comment: какое отношение питон к этому вопросу имеет?¶ Попробуйте более наглядно представить, что сейчас происходит и что вы хотите вместо этого получить. (пример в виде самодостаточного [code snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/4279) попробуйте сделать, а желаемый результат хоть ручками в редакторе подрисуйте и в вопрос в виде картинки добавьте).

Comment: Питон имеет прямое отношение. Я указал, что использую networkx библиотеку для создания графа и пример основан на вот этом вот примере: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/tree/master/examples/javascript/force  хочется получить что-то вроде https://www.dropbox.com/s/iwxo2cgdmahdtm3/index.html?dl=0

Comment: От того что данные в Питоне получены, а не любым другим способом, код, который стрелочки вместо линий создаёт, как то изменится?

Comment: вряд ли, но мб необходимо будет по-другому формировать source-target вершины, а не просто списком.